# Sorting with Active Record and showing all duplicate values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Active Record I'm running a sort query to display all of my data in descending order on a column called "review_count".  The problem is that what displays is only one of each item with any given review count.

**Example:**

- Place 1: 10 Reviews
- Place 2: 10 Reviews
- Place 3: 10 Reviews
- Place 4: 3 Reviews
- Place 5: 2 Reviews
- Place 6: 2 Reviews

Running this query: `Destination.group(:review_count).order("review_count DESC")`, the resulting output would be:

- Place 1: 10 Reviews
- Place 4: 3 Reviews
- Place 5: 2 Reviews

How can I show all ordered values, instead of only distinct values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `review_count` is simply a counter, so that there is no need to use `group(:review_count)` here.  Just `Destination.order("review_count DESC")` gives you what you want.